# How can I check the indexes of my tables?

Tags: join, indexing, phpmyadmin

I have a website using phpymyadmin, and when I go to 'status', it tells me the following: "The number of joins that do not use indexes. If this value is not 0, you should carefully check the indexes of your tables." The number is not 0, it is 101 right now, but it was above 24K before the server was reset this weekend.

This is an example of a query I have. Not sure where am I going wrong with my JOINS, can someone help me letting me know if I'm missing something, or if I'm being redundant here, or maybe a little explanation on how to work my index situation.

```sql
SELECT pe_projects . *
     , pe_project_status.status_t
     , pe_project_status.orderby
     , pe_pocs.first_name AS  'poc_first_name'
     , pe_pocs.last_name 'poc_last_name'
     , pe_clients.id AS  'client_id'
     , pe_clients.short_name
     , pe_employees.first_name AS  'pe_first_name'
     , pe_employees.last_name AS  'pe_last_name'
     , (SELECT COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id)
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking
          WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS total_inst
     , (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id)
                  FROM pe_instrument_tracking
                  WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.ordered IS NOT NULL
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.ordered <> '0000-00-00'
               )/COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id) *100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking
          WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS ordered_per
     , (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id)
                  FROM pe_instrument_tracking
                  WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.received IS NOT NULL
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.received <> '0000-00-00'
               )/COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id) *100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking
          WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS received_per
     , (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id)
                  FROM pe_instrument_tracking
                  WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.installed IS NOT NULL
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.installed <> '0000-00-00'
               )/COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id) *100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking
          WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS installed_per
     , (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id)
                  FROM pe_instrument_tracking
                  WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.tested IS NOT NULL
                    AND pe_instrument_tracking.tested <> '0000-00-00'
               )/COUNT(pe_instrument_tracking.id) *100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking
          WHERE pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS tested_per
  FROM pe_projects
  JOIN pe_project_status ON pe_projects.status_id = pe_project_status.id
  JOIN pe_pocs ON pe_projects.client_contact_id = pe_pocs.id
  JOIN pe_clients ON pe_projects.client_id = pe_clients.id
  JOIN pe_employees ON pe_projects.employee_id = pe_employees.id
  WHERE NOT pe_projects.deleted
    AND pe_projects.department='1'
```

Comment: I've tried to improve the formatting of the code so it's readable. Was this query machine-generated? If this is a query you wrote yourself, as it was originally presented, then (and I do not say this lightly) your DB structure may not be your most urgent problem.

Comment: Regarding your actual question: the message you're seeing is _not_ saying there's something wrong with your joins _per se_. It's saying that your DB structure isn't set up to efficiently support the queries that are actually happening. Do you, for example, have primary keys and foreign keys in all the right places? I would suggest taking this question over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and giving them some more contextual detail about the application and database.

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter I appreciate the edits on the format, I am fairly new here, so didn't know how to post it properly. So, are you saying that maybe my first and most important worry should be working on a better query??

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That typically includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)  For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL which includes constraints & indexes. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say where you should start, but as far as I can tell, based on the question prior to my edit

- You had a large sql query in as a string-literal in php.
- It was completely unformatted.
- It was written in a complex and repetitive way.

All of which makes mistakes likely, difficult to identify, and difficult to fix.

- Putting sql in its own file may be a good idea. Other options include using query-builder tools, or moving the complexity of the query into your database as a DB view.
- Always format all your code for readability and maintainability. This is so that people will be able to help you with it.
- `x <> NULL` is `NULL`, which is falsy, so you don't need to separately test for NULLs.
- You can *probably* use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(table.id)`, which is more readable, but if `table.id` doesn't mean what it looks like it means than maybe this isn't right.
- The double-nested `SELECT`s are a big red flag, both in terms of readability and performance. You can get rid of them by relying on the fact that when you *don't* use `COUNT(*)`, COUNT doesn't count `NULL`s.
- Consider *always* using aliases for tables, but if you're using the same table multiple times in a query, then you should *certainly* alias it each time.
- Always use explicit JOIN types, and be mindful of the differences between them.

```sql
SELECT pe_projects.*
     , pe_project_status.status_t
     , pe_project_status.orderby
     , pe_pocs.first_name AS 'poc_first_name'
     , pe_pocs.last_name AS 'poc_last_name'
     , pe_clients.id AS 'client_id'
     , pe_clients.short_name
     , pe_employees.first_name AS 'pe_first_name'
     , pe_employees.last_name AS 'pe_last_name'
     , (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking pit
          WHERE pit.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS total_inst
     , (SELECT COUNT(
                 CASE WHEN pit_o.ordered <> '0000-00-00' THEN pit_o.id END
               ) / COUNT(*) * 100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking pit_o
          WHERE pit_o.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS ordered_per
     , (SELECT COUNT(
                 CASE WHEN pit_r.received <> '0000-00-00' THEN pit_r.id END
               ) / COUNT(*) * 100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking pit_r
          WHERE pit_r.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS received_per
     , (SELECT COUNT(
                 CASE WHEN pit_i.installed <> '0000-00-00' THEN pit_i.id END
               ) / COUNT(*) * 100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking pit_i
          WHERE pit_i.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS installed_per
     , (SELECT COUNT(
                 CASE WHEN pit_t.tested <> '0000-00-00' THEN pit_t.id END
               ) / COUNT(*) * 100
          FROM pe_instrument_tracking pit_t
          WHERE pit_t.project_id = pe_projects.id
       ) AS tested_per
  FROM pe_projects
  LEFT JOIN pe_project_status ON pe_projects.status_id = pe_project_status.id
  LEFT JOIN pe_pocs ON pe_projects.client_contact_id = pe_pocs.id
  LEFT JOIN pe_clients ON pe_projects.client_id = pe_clients.id
  LEFT JOIN pe_employees ON pe_projects.employee_id = pe_employees.id
  WHERE NOT pe_projects.deleted
    AND pe_projects.department = '1'
```

The above is still not great. In particular, there are five subqueries against the single table `pe_instrument_tracking`. Assuming you're on a reasonably up-to-date version of MySQL, you can fix that with a "derived table" type subquery:

```sql
SELECT pe_projects.*
     , pe_project_status.status_t
     , pe_project_status.orderby
     , pe_pocs.first_name AS 'poc_first_name'
     , pe_pocs.last_name AS 'poc_last_name'
     , pe_clients.id AS 'client_id'
     , pe_clients.short_name
     , pe_employees.first_name AS 'pe_first_name'
     , pe_employees.last_name AS 'pe_last_name'
     , pit.total AS total_inst
     , pit.ordered AS ordered_per
     , pit.received AS received_per
     , pit.installed AS installed_per
     , pit.tested AS tested_per
  FROM pe_projects
  LEFT JOIN pe_project_status ON pe_projects.status_id = pe_project_status.id
  LEFT JOIN pe_pocs ON pe_projects.client_contact_id = pe_pocs.id
  LEFT JOIN pe_clients ON pe_projects.client_id = pe_clients.id
  LEFT JOIN pe_employees ON pe_projects.employee_id = pe_employees.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
                  , 100
                      * COUNT(CASE WHEN pe_instrument_tracking.ordered <> '0000-00-00' THEN 1 END)
                      / COUNT(*) AS ordered
                  , 100
                      * COUNT(CASE WHEN pe_instrument_tracking.received <> '0000-00-00' THEN 1 END)
                      / COUNT(*) AS received
                  , 100
                      * COUNT(CASE WHEN pe_instrument_tracking.installed <> '0000-00-00' THEN 1 END)
                      / COUNT(*) AS installed
                  , 100
                      * COUNT(CASE WHEN pe_instrument_tracking.tested <> '0000-00-00' THEN 1 END)
                      / COUNT(*) AS tested
               FROM pe_instrument_tracking ON pe_instrument_tracking.project_id = pe_projects.id
            ) AS pit
  WHERE NOT pe_projects.deleted
    AND pe_projects.department = '1'
```

## Note that none of this addresses the warning message you're actually asking about.

But now that you have a shorter, more intelligible query, you can hopefully start to reason about what kinds of keys and indexes it will need to run efficiently.

Comment: thank you very much for this! It is really helpful, I will dig deep on all your explanation and go from there!!